# Order threads by the number of posts

Tags: mysql

I got a table with threads and one with posts. I want to list these ordered by the number of post associated to them.

Example structure of my tables

**Posts table:**

```
id   creator    replyTo    text    timestamp
1    1          1          Bla     2011-11-11 11:11
2    2          2          Alb     2011-11-11 11:11
3    3          3          Lba     2011-11-11 11:11
4    4          1          Lab     2011-11-11 11:11
5    5          2          Bal     2011-11-11 11:11
6    2          2          Abl     2011-11-11 11:11
```

**Threads table:**

```
id  creator     name       content    timestamp
1   1           BlaBla     BlaBla     2011-11-11 11:11
2   3           AlbAlb     AlbAlb     2011-11-11 11:11
3   2           LbaLba     LbaLab     2011-11-11 11:11
```

**Example output:**

```
id  creator     name       count      timestamp
2   3           AlbAlb     3          2011-11-11 11:11
1   1           BlaBla     2          2011-11-11 11:11
3   2           LbaLba     1          2011-11-11 11:11
```

Comment: How are posts and threads connected? Does `posts.replyto` reference `threads.id`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.creator, t.name, count(*) AS ct, t.timestamp
FROM   threads t
JOIN   posts p ON p.replyTo = t.id
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC, 1,2;
```

Produces exactly the requested results.
See the [working demo here](http://sqlize.com/8Qbn34s6AB).

```
GROUP  BY 1
```

is short for (because it is enough to group by the primary key in mysql):

```
GROUP  BY 1,2,3,5
```

which is short for (because these are positional parameters):

```
GROUP  BY t.id, t.creator, t.name, t.timestamp
```

#### Answer to additional question in comment

Add a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.creator, t.name, count(*) AS ct, t.timestamp
FROM   threads t
JOIN   posts p ON p.replyTo = t.id
WHERE  t.timestamp BETWEEN (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
                       AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC, 1,2;
```

Comment: Bonus question, if I want to limit my request to only threads created the last 24 hours, how should I do this?

Comment: @Victor: I added an answer to my answer.

Comment: @Erwin, awesome! Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: I think it will work, but on large database it will became slow.

Comment: @MosheL: This statement is as simple as it gets. You can speed up with proper indexes or with a materialized view if you are desperate. Maybe grouping by day instead of a dynamic 24h window (for the 2nd answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id, t.creator, t.name, COUNT(1) AS postCount, t.timestamp
FROM threads AS t
INNER JOIN posts AS p ON t.id = p.replyTo
GROUP BY t.id, t.creator, t.name, t.timestamp
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 t.id, t.creator, t.name, count(p.id) as count, t.timestamp
FROM
 threads t
  INNER JOIN posts p ON
    t.id = p.replyTo
GROUP BY
 t.id, t.creator, t.name, t.timestamp
ORDER BY 
 count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Threads.*, COUNT(*) post_count
FROM Threads LEFT JOIN Posts ON Threads.id = Posts.replyTo
GROUP BY Threads.id /* Technically you are supposed to list all columns here, but in MySQL it works fine to just list the primary key */
ORDER BY post_count
```

Method two:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts WHERE Threads.id = Posts.replyTo) post_count
FROM Threads
ORDER BY post_count
```

Note: Your column names are not good. You should not name all the ids the same, it makes it harder than necessary to join tables. Change `replyTo` to `thread_id`, change the `id` of threads to `thread_id`, and posts to `post_id`.

Comment: Both of your options are missing the `count` column in the output from the OP.